# Check device state from Device Manager in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, device-manager

I want to check if device is enabled or disabled using python. I want to make a program that would toggle touchscreen on my laptop.

I tried looking for module or cmd command that could do this, but I didn't find any solutions.

Comment: What exactly do "device is enabled" and "device is disabled" mean?  What does "toggle touchscreen" mean?  I do not know what you are asking for.

Comment: In device manager you can disable or enable device, that looks something like [this](https://imgur.com/a/yGs5z0m). I want to check state of it. If you need any more info let me know.

Comment: That screenshot is so generic, I have no idea what it is actually meant to do.  Please explain what "disabling a device" **actually means**.

Comment: If you disable a device it won't function at all. For example, I have a camera and I disable it, it won't work until I enable it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two choices for you.

Everything that Device Manager does is done through the "setupapi.dll" APIs, which all start with SetupDi.  Here is a sample module which can iterate through your devices and return their attributes:

https://github.com/gwangyi/pysetupdi

Alternatively, there is a command called "pnputil" that ships with Windows that can enumerate, enable, and disable devices by their hardware IDs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil-command-syntax

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer, I can't seem to find any docs whatsoever. As for pnputil, I can't see state of device, I can only enable/disable device.

Comment: With `/enum-devices`, your device will be present if enabled.